# Using .iloc and .isin to filter columns based on the value of the second row (not first) in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter out columns without a particular string as the second row value. In this case, let's say I only want the columns with `Apple` in them to display, and the `Kiwi` columns to not be displayed.

It works no problem if the string value is in the first row instead, however, it does not work at all in the second row. I know a change is required in the fourth line of code bolded below, but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'K:\blah blah\blah\\sampledata.xlsx'

inp = pd.read_excel(file, header=1)

result = inp.iloc[:, inp.columns.isin(['Apple'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole `DataFrame` and drop `Kiwi` from the columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Apple": [1, 2, 3], "Kiwi": [4, 5, 6]})
df.drop(columns="Kiwi")
```

Otherwise, you can specify the columns you don't want in a function passed to `usecols`:

```py
pd.read_excel(file, usecols=lambda col: "Kiwi" not in col)
```

This method should be faster https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

I think first and second rows of data are headers, so use `header=[0,1]` for `MultiIndex` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
inp = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1])
```

And then select by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = inp.xs('Bananas', axis=1, level=1)
```